# Error after trying to import values into database

Tags: c#, sql, null

When I try to import values into database, I always got the error  -

> System.Data.NoNullAllowedException: 'Column 'Vards' does not allow nulls.

Even though I have implemented my table correct.

Table code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Darbinieki_Parasti] 
(
    [Id]         INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Vards]      NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Alga_Pirms] DECIMAL(18)  NULL,
    [Alga_Pec]   DECIMAL(18)  NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Darbinieki_Parasti] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Insert code:

```
appData.Darbinieki_Parasti.AddDarbinieki_ParastiRow(appData.Darbinieki_Parasti.NewDarbinieki_ParastiRow());
darbiniekiParastiBindingSource.MoveLast();
```

When I enter data manually it works.

I have bonded data fields with database table.

Comment: If you are using MS SQL Server, try using SQL Server Profiler to see the actual SQL code that is being executed. Profiler can be found in SQL Management Studio, menu Tools | SQL Server profiler

Comment: are you sure this is the actual Table code? if it defined as NULL,definitely it should allow null values.

Comment: @Tom I use inbuild LocalDB in Visual Basic that comes with .net package..

Comment: @user9405863 Yes, when i open the database section it shows the code. Also either the field is empty or not, it shows the same error.

Comment: Did you update the EF model?

Comment: @Caramiriel Entity Framework model, no. If so how can i do it?

Comment: @Krizs Cant find the proper page, but this should be accurate enough: https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/cc716705(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the Entity Framework model.
Go in the edmx file, and check the field properties.
Change the nullable value, or if you want, delete the object "Darbinieki_Parasti" and update from database again.

Comment: i just generated edmx and putted vards = nullable , still the same error. Even when i enter the data it says "nullable is not allowed"